# i18next init on specific language

Tags: node.js, localization, internationalization, i18next

I'm using i18next-node for localization of my app.

I have two languages: `en-CA` and `fr-CA`

I'm using this to init the app:

```
i18next.init({
    saveMissing: true,
    sendMissingTo : 'all',
    ignoreRoutes: ['img/','images/', 'public/', 'css/', 'js/'],
    debug: true,
    lng: 'en-CA'
});
```

The problem is, when I start the app, it gives me this error:

```
currentLng set to: en-US
[ { [Error: ENOENT, open 'locales/en-US/translation.json']
    errno: 34,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    path: 'locales/en-US/translation.json' } ]
```

I don't want en-US, I want en-CA. Now, my app isn't showing either language. How do I set en-CA to be the default?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can set `fallbackLng : 'en-CA'` and that will work. Kind of a hack though.

Comment: that's not a hack. fallbackLng it was is displayed when a user requests your site with a language you don't support.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the detect language section under http://i18next.com/node/pages/doc_init.html

i18next detects during the request the language from your browser-settings (if not set by any other methode - cookie, querystring). That's why language is set to 'en-US'.

You can set the supported languages on init:
i18n.init({supportedLngs: ['en-CA', 'fr-CA']})

But you still need to set a fallbackLng -> eg. if someone requests your page with language set 'de' some fallback language should be displayed.